# Which ideas from String Theory are useful in other fields?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, black-holes, condensed-matter, string-theory

I hear sometimes that ideas in String Theory (ST) turned useful in other fields. I am curious, what are these ideas, and what insights or tools did they provide (that otherwise would not be discovered without ST)? Would a condensed matter theorist/particle physicist/etc. (not a mathematician) gain any new insights in their fields by studying studying String theory?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monstrous_moonshine

Comment: Voting to close as lacking focus because: 1. This question is asking for an open-ended list of examples, which is generally a bad fit for our Q&A format. 2. It is unclear/ambiguous what distinguishes an "idea in String Theory" from e.g. "math that happens to be used in String Theory", making it hard to tell what qualifies as an answer and what doesn't.

Comment: I specified, that the question is more about application of string theory ideas/math in other areas of physics, that otherwise would not exist. Is it specific enough now?

Comment: @ACuriousMind The question seems pretty specific now. Is there any problem with it at this point?